# Is there a way to record multi-threaded the mixed result of JavaFX AudioClip sounds to disk?

Tags: java-audio

My program  launchs an arbitrary number of sounds streamed from FreeSound.org and plays them using javafx.scene.media AudioClip instances.

I was trying to figure out whether it could be possible to capture the generated output to disk, from within the same program? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `AudioClip` you could use `SourceDataLine` for playback. This class allows you to progressively read the audio data, exposing it for handling. You would have to decode from bytes to PCM for each incoming line, then add the PCM from all the lines to be merged, and recode that back to bytes for your output.

I suspect with a little minor tweaking you could get the library I wrote `AudioCue` to work for you. It has an optional mixer that will handle multiple cue inputs. The inputs make use of `SourceDataLine` and the mixer uses the logic I described. You would have to tweak the code to output to disk. I could probably help with that if this project is still live for you.